# openni_kinect driver on Windows

Tags: openni-kinect, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run multiple Kinects on a Windows machine. I heard that the ROS openni_kinect driver can be used to do this and from the ROS kinect wiki, it seems that [Windows is supported](http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect#Choose_your_driver).

But it does not mention any installation instructions for Windows. Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10693/openni_kinect-driver-on-windows/) by [Jacob](https://answers.ros.org/users/873/jacob/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If all you need is multiple kinects, you should use the raw (non-ROS) openni driver, found here: http://www.openni.org/downloadfiles/opennimodules with documentation here: http://www.openni.org/documentation .
This driver should work on Windows. Getting ROS up and running on Windows is a whole different beast, and if all you need is the kinect, not the right solution.

Keep in mind that a kinect will saturate an entire USB bus: so if you want a computer to have multiple kinects, make sure they are on different physical USB buses.

---

Originally posted by [Helen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1033/helen/) with karma: 261 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0